# Cutting Cabinet for larger Wall/Microwave Combo oven?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, oven, cutting, custom-cabinetry

[image]

I would like to DIY my Wall Oven/Microwave combo replacement and have an interesting situation.  The unit I am replacing is an old Kitchen Aid unit (that is working fine currently and I am not rushing to replace).  I would like to put in an LG unit as my fridge and dishwasher are LG so I'd like them to match.
The problem seems to be that not every manufacturers wall oven/microwave combos seem to be the same height. My current Kitchen Aid is quite a bit shorter than the new unit specs.
The picture is of the current unit with some measurements (in inches) of gaps between upper and lower cabinets and height of the unit itself.  I will also share the specs of the new unit.

Old Unit Height Specs

- Unit Height - 42 7/16
- Cutout Height - 41 1/4

Potential new unit specs

- Unit Height - 43 13/16
- Cutout Height - 43 7/16

I guess what I'm asking is I am curious how to handle this.  It seems as though I'd have to cut or adjust the upper or lower cabinet.  Has anyone done this before? Make the bottom cabinet smaller or top? Cutting down cabinet doors?

Comment: Can't see the pic right now, unfortunately, but often there are filler pieces on the cabinets that are used to trim the cabinet to tightly fit the installed appliance (both in height & width). If that's the case here, you'd be able to remove the oven, remove the filler, carefully measure the new height (to make sure that the actual installed height matches expectations), then cut the filler to fit, making the new opening taller to allow the new unit to fit in. If you see extra wood around the opening (in comparison to other cabinets) you have filler pieces that can be cut.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for responding!  My Dilemma is I have 44 inches between the bottom of the top cabinet door and the top of the lower drawer.  I dont think I have filler pieces? Wish the picture would load

Comment: @Matt, You cannot count on the measurement from door or drawer edges. You need to allow for the box as well.

Comment: Thanks RMD.  Wasnt necessarily counting on the measurement. More just trying to provide a visual and rough measurement to show my predicament.  Essentially if I did cut out big enough to fit the the new unit would basically touch the bottom of the top door and top of the lower drawers so I'd need to alter the doors

Comment: You need to understand where the shelf from the upper cabinet is. If there’s 44 from the shelf above the drawer to the underside of the shelf in the cab above, then it’ll probably work. If not, keep shopping.

Comment: Thanks! I follow and that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

I would lean toward mounting the oven lower and cutting down the drawer. Only one panel to adjust instead of two. Low to the ground so DIY adjustments might not be as visible. The drawer box itself might not need cutting down, if it is somewhat less tall than the opening it is in.

Whether you decide to go up or down, you'll need some decent cabinet-making and woodworking skills to make the adjustments, as well as matching paint and other finish to match the existing finish. You may have to break apart the drawer front or doors into their 5 pieces and trim the bottom of the side stiles, trim half of the required amount from top and bottom of the center panel of the drawer or the dull amount from the top of the door panels, and glue the pieces back together again. Removal of the rail between the desired opening and the oven opening to move the rail the required amount may require a new piece of wood for the rail if it must be cut out. The fixed panel holding the oven up or the bottom panel of the door section must be adjusted.

It may be possible to get replacement doors or drawer front from the cabinetry manufacturer, which would make it unnecessary to break up and re-assemble the doors or drawer front. Matching finish may be a problem if the cabinets are older.

Comment: The concern with this plan is that wall ovens require a sturdy base. (Last one I did specified 400# capacity.) Removing and sturdily replacing the platform the oven sits on is going to be tough.

Comment: Yes, it is a tricky project. Not impossible if one has the skills, but needs some good thought and decent wood, screws, brackets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cut cabinet doors and have them look proper.

The only option appears to be removing the upper cabinet and replacing it with a  shorter unit.

If you know the manufacturer of the cabinets you can order a new cabinet that is shorter.

If you do not know where the cabinets are from, you can ask a cabinet shop if they can make a new matching cabinet to the correct needed size.

Possibly the least expense would be removing the cabinet and having a handyman or carpenter make shelves over the new unit.

Comment: I think this is likely a single tall cabinet with three openings in it. The top part is probably not a separate unit that can be switched out.

Comment: A single unit would be common in a full custom cabinet suite.   This looks like individual cabinets with a panel that is visible on the left and right side.

Comment: I've seen full height oven cabinets with top, oven, and bottom all one unit in cookie cutter store-bought kitchens, one reference https://www.cabinetplaceonline.com/tall-conestoga-cabinets/ see the ovens about 3/4 down, but these cabinets could come both ways.

Comment: Really appreciate the input everyone! I can confirm its one solid cabinet from bottom to top with the 3 openings. I think confirming that means that this is way too difficult for me to do by myself for it to look presentable. How frustrating that they arent all standard heights

Comment: Agree that cutting cabinet doors is rarely a winning proposition, but there might be room between the door and the crown to adjust upwards a tiny bit, and in extreme circumstances (repainting being a huge problem) you could trim a fat 16th from the top and bottom without drawing too much attention.

Comment: I disagree that you can't cut cabinet doors and have them look proper.  It depends what they're made of and how they're finished.  I would argue that a decent cabinetmaker could easily shorten the doors pictured.  The hard part would be matching the color and finish, depending how picky the OP is about that.  The real issue here may be what the interior dimensions of the cabinet are—how much the height is between the cavity floor and ceiling vs. the height of the new appliance.

Comment: The OP was advised that THEY could not cut cabinet doors and have them look right.  Yes a good cabinet maker can do magic. But that is not what is being said.